# Replace specific content in line in html with JS

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I've got a html file and JS file

So I've got a syntax of svg in my html file :

```
<body>
    <svg width="500" height="100">
        <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
        style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>  
        <text x="47.872" y="11.064">{home/sensors/temp/kitchen} °C</text>
        <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
        style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
        <title x="47.872" y="11.064" >{home/sensors/temp/bathroom} °C</title>
        <circle id="circle1" cx="20" cy="20" r="10"
        style="stroke: none; fill: #ff0000;"/>
        <text x="47.872" y="11.064">{home/sensors/temp/room} °C</text>
    </svg>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/link.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Currently, I've got only this in my link.js:

```
let listTickets = new Map([
                          ['0', '{home/sensors/temp/kitchen}'],
                          ['1', '{home/sensors/temp/bathroom}'],
                          ['2',  '{home/sensors/temp/room}']
]);

let listNumber = new Map([
                          ['0', '24'],
                          ['1', '22'],
                          ['2', '25']
]);

// var topicMatch = line.match(/\{[\w\/]+\}/g); // think need to use regex
```

So What I want in my js file, it's when we've got a syntax in html file like:

```
"{ + content + }
```

Need to replace (in my navigator and not in file) the same syntax by his value, for example, we are reading the html file :

```
detect first content : {home/sensors/temp/kitchen} => need to change by '24'
detect second content : {home/sensors/temp/bathroom} => need to change by '22'
detect first content : {home/sensors/temp/kitchen} => need to change by '25'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this JS code:

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {
  for (let [key, value] of listTickets) {
    if (all[i].innerHTML.includes(value)) {
      all[i].innerHTML=all[i].innerHTML.replaceAll(value, listNumber.get(key));
    }
  }
}
```

It finds any match of given strings in the `listTickets` map in your html, and changes them with the value of `listNumber` map for string's key.

Answer (score 1):

You get more flexibility with a modern Web Component (supported in all modern Browsers)

And process your *source* SVG as a Template Literal String to replace values (or execute functions like: `color` does)

```html
<temperature-dashboard cold="blue" warm="red">
  <template inside template so SVG is not displayed on load>
    <svg id="temperature" width="100" height="120">
      <style>
        #temperature { background:pink}
        #temperature circle { stroke:none; r:${size}}
      </style>
      <circle cx="20" cy="20"  ${color(kitchen)} ></circle>
      <text x="40" y="25">${kitchen} °C</text>
      <circle cx="20" cy="60"  ${color(bathroom)} ></circle>
      <text x="40" y="65">${bathroom} °C</text>
      <circle cx="20" cy="100" ${color(room)} ></circle>
      <text x="40" y="105">${room} °C</text>
    </svg>
  </template>
</temperature-dashboard>
<script>
  customElements.define("temperature-dashboard", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML is fully parsed
        this.svgsource = this.querySelector("template").innerHTML;
        let data = { bathroom: 23, kitchen: 24, room: 19 };
        this.setdata( data );
      })
    }
    setdata( dataIn ){
      let fulldata = { 
            size: 15,
            color : (degrees) => {
              let coldColor = this.getAttribute("cold");
              let warmColor = this.getAttribute("warm");
              return `fill="${degrees < 20 ? coldColor : warmColor }"`
            },
            ...dataIn
      }
      const parseTemplateLiteral = (str, data = {}) => {
        let params = Object.keys(data).join(",");
        return new Function("p", // Function savely parsing Template Literal
               "return((" + params + ")=>`" + str + "`)(...Object.values(p))")(data);
      }
      this.innerHTML = parseTemplateLiteral(this.svgsource, fulldata);
    }
  });
</script>
```